# Help using tooltip.js with tagsphere.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I know that Tagsphere.js deletes the UL and turns all the LI into DIV and erases all the title attributes.

I hacked tagsphere.js to included the title attributes of my LIs and so now all my tags give nice default tool tip messages.

I also have tooltip.js working will all my A tags giving them cool tooltips.

Now I need to find a way to make them work together in harmony.

Anyone familiar with tooltip.js and tagsphere.js and know of a way to make them work together?

Answer (score 0):

No worries.
I just put my tooltips function call into $(document).ready and it works fine.

```
//
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').tooltip();
});
//
```